# How to make new folder in askdirectory dialog?

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter in python 3.4, how to create folder using askdirectory dialog?

```
from tkinter import filedialog

filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/tmp/test")
```

This shows choos directory window, but cant see option to create new folder. For example, /tmp/test/new_folder. usually choose directory window have button to make new folder, but cant find option in tkinter.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is anything in `askdirectory` for that. You may have to use [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.makedirs#os.makedirs) for it

Comment: What is the operating system you're using?

Answer (score 3):

I wish Tkinter included a New Folder button on the Linux platform, but it doesn't seem to. The best I could do was to just type the new folder name in the text field, and then create the new folder after the dialog box closes.

```
def process_files(self):
    savedir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title='Select folder to save results')
    os.makedirs(savedir)
    # Now write some files into savedir.
```

Comment: You can use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) instead of custom recursive function.